# Javascript Error Handling example

Tags: javascript

I have two functions one which checks the value of id and makes sure its 0 or greater else throws an error.

```js
function getPerson(id) {
 if (id < 0) {
  throw new Error('ID must not be negative '+id);
 }
 return {id:id};
}

function getPersons(ids) {
 var result = [];
  ids.forEach(function (id) {
    try {
     var person = getPerson(id);
     result.push(person);
    } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
    
getPersons([2, -5, 137]);
```

Now I am reading a book called **Speaking Javascript by Dr.Axel Rauschmayer**
and this is an example from the book. I am curious as to why the error being thrown isn't being caught.

My desired result would be for it to log the error but keep running and return the result array.

Comment: [It catches the error for me](https://jsfiddle.net/rafc5twb/). What do you expect it to do here? If you put the try-catch in your loop, then it will catch on that one iteration of the loop, and then continue the loop.

Comment: Nobody answered what the OP wants to understand. My goodness!

Comment: I think maybe what is confusing you is that it is logging the entire `Error` object, which includes the stack trace. This looks very similar to what you would see if the program crashed. But in this case it continues. Try saving the return value from `getPersons()` and log it to the console. You'll see that this is behaving the way you want it to.

Comment: @ele I don't understand what OP wants to understand here. OP suggests that this code isn't doing something, but testing shows that it is.

Comment: @Thebluefish *My desired result would be for it to log the error but keep running and return the result array*

Comment: throw 'ID must not be negative '+id;  use this then

Comment: @Ele that's what it already does.

Comment: but ideally you wouldnt want to do that

Comment: Thanks Mark_M i was getting confused because of the stack trace and thought it was crashing and stopping the loop iteration. I wasn't seeing the the two objects being returned because i never logged them. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Just to reiterate because this is a common mistake that is easy to make, you should not use `throw` in the course of normal operation.

Comment: Thank you Marie. I was just going through an exercise in a book i'm reading to gain a deeper understanding on Javascript. Appreciate all of your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the error object being logged, but instead of logging just the error object, log the error's message and you will see that the error is, in fact, being thrown as you designed it.

```js
function getPerson(id) {
 if (id < 0) {
  throw new Error('ID must not be negative '+id);
 }
 return {id:id};
}

function getPersons(ids) {
 var result = [];
  ids.forEach(function (id) {
    try {
     var person = getPerson(id);
     result.push(person);
    } catch (err) {
     console.log(err.message);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
    
getPersons([2, -5, 137]);
```

**NOTES:**

- I realize you are working your way through an exercise here but
  understand that throwing and catching errors is something that should
  be done as a last resort and only in situations where an exception
  could be thrown through no fault of your own (i.e. network and
  server-side failures). This is because throwing exceptions and catch
  blocks have performance implications. When something doesn't meet
  your criteria, return a special value that indicates that and check
  for that value in other places.
- Even when `try/catch` is warranted, it is a best-practice to never
  place them inside of a loop (again for performance reasons). If you
  loop goes 10,000 times and you encounter numerous errors, each one of
  them will be caught and handled, dramatically affecting performance.
  Instead place the loop inside of the `try` section and, upon the
  first error, the code will proceed to the `catch`.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I appreciate your answer!

Comment: @AdrianLineweaver You're welcome. See my last update in the NOTES section.

Comment: Thanks once again! I had a little bit of a brain fart which led me to post this question and i managed to learn a lot from your answer because of it @Scott Marcus

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the attribute [`message`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Error_instances) from object [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Error_instances).

```js
function getPerson(id) {
  if (id < 0) throw new Error('ID must not be negative ' + id); 
  return {id};
}


function getPersons(ids) {
  var result = [];
  ids.forEach(function(id) {
    try {
      var person = getPerson(id);
      result.push(person);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  });
  return result;
}

getPersons([2, -5, 137]);
```

Comment: Thanks Ele even though its not the accepted answer i appreciate it!